# Is it possible to drag&drop a file from filesystem to WinJS modern app?

Tags: drag-and-drop, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm trying to use HTML5 `drop` event, but it doesn't seem to fire. I also get a crossed circle cursor when I'm trying to drag&drop a file. On the other hand drag&drop html elements works fine. Any suggestions? Is it a limitation for the modern windows apps?

Answer (score 1):

In UWP (win10) it's possible to drag and drop content from another source to your app. When files are dropped in your app, you only have read access to that file though, not sure if that's enough for you.

Have a look at [the XAML sample on how to implement drag and drop](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop). API works the same for JS.

Martin